# Значение параметра через регулярные выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения, javascript

Задача в том, чтобы получить значение параметра. Значением параметра будет строка состоящая из латинских букв и цифр разнообразной комбинации. Пример:

```
sid=testcd52c49ecb525cb985
sid=52c49ecb525cb985
```

За значением параметра может идти другой параметр, параметы разделены символом &.
Соответственно, мне нужно получить только *52c49ecb525cb985* или *testcd52c49ecb525cb985* и записать в переменную.

У меня получилось получить значение  начинающееся с буквы таким способом:

```
/sid=(\w+)/
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как дополнить регулярку.

Comment: @Expert  дополнил вопрос

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/sid=(testcd)?(\w+)/
```

Comment: параметр может иметь значение 52c49ecb525cb985 либо testcd52c49ecb525cb985, какой формат придет я могу предсказать

Comment: @helplz обновил пример http://jsfiddle.net/6Q4Xb/1/

Comment: когда я беру значение параметра из урла у меня не поулчается (( 
sid = (window.location.search.match(/sid=\w+/) || [null, null])[1]

Comment: @helplz я вам обновил пример.

Comment: @lampa спасибо за ответы, но ваш пример выводит много вариантов, мне нужно получить одну строку состоящую из латинского алфавита и цифр и записать ее в переменную.

Comment: @helplz во втором комментарии консоль выдает именно одиночные строки. Пожалуйста, посмотрите внимательнее.